# Помогите подобрать почтовый сервер

Tags: ubuntu, email

Интересует почтовый сервер для Ubuntu, с возможностью хранение писем не на диске, а в базе данных (MongoDB, MySQL). Пожалуйста, подскажите, какой выбрать?

Comment: @Dcbal, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем вы видите проблему, как ее воспроизвести и т. д. Вопросы опросники запрещены в сообществе.

Comment: @Dcbal, боюсь, что де-факто существуют только два стандарта хранения: mailbox и maildir, оба на основе файлов. В принципе, задачу можно решить через монтирование сетевого диска.

Answer (score 1):

1. Зачем хранить письма в БД? Я понимаю, учтные данные пользователей, но письма...

А вот ответ на ваш вопрос http://www.dbmail.org/ + postfix + dovecot Ваше все.

Comment: Скажем так, писем много, и размер большой, не хватает места на диске.

Comment: А база данных хранит их что, в воздухе? Она их также будет хранить на диске. И ещё далеко не факт, что места будет занимать меньше.

Comment: Ну бд вам тут не сильно поможет, разве что она будет на отдельной машине с отдельным дисковым пространством и большим объемом ОЗУ, чтоб хранить данные в RAM и как можно меньше читать с диска. А также если есть возможность, то перенести данные на дисковую полку.  
Если же у вас есть дисковое пространство на другой машине, как вариант, можно прикрутить nfs. В общем, тут несколько архитектурных решений, все зависит от того, что вы имеете сейчас (железо\os\soft\кол-во пользователей) и что планируете сделать.